# Executing JS string parameters as methods

Tags: javascript

I have to build a function that will execute some tasks.

The tasks will be a parameter of the function, most likely a string array.
It might look something like this :

```
['refresh', 'close', 'show']
```

The strings correspond to actual methods.

Is it possible to somehow execute the methods by using the strings of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Yup:

```
var method = "refresh";
yourObject[method]();
```

---

**Long answer:**

It's possible, but your methods *must* be namespaced. 
The following example will work, if you're in a browser context, because every global function is a property of `window`:

```
function refresh() {
    // do it
}
var method = "refresh";
window[method]();

// or maybe
var yourObject = { refresh: function() { ... } };
yourObject[method]();
```

However, the following won't work (I'm showing it because closures are a common pattern in javascript):

```
(function() {
   function refresh() {
       // do it
   }

   var method = "refresh";
   // which object contains refresh...? None!
   // yourObject[method]();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

if your methods are attached to the window object then you can do something like this:

```
var methods = [ 'refresh', 'close', 'show' ];
for( var i in methods ) {
    funk = window[ methods[ i ] ];
    if( typeof funk === 'function') {
        window.funk();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if your methods are methods of another object you can easily replace window with your object.